# how to get values stored in Shared Preference in flutter and pass those to a function?

Tags: flutter

as per the question I have to call a function through which I am calling an API which will register the user and that will take parameters as per the value which stored in Shared Preference.

So below is the fuction.

**api_service.dart**

```
    class ApiService{
     registerUser(String fName, String mobileNo, String lName) async{
        Dio dio = new Dio(options);
        FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
          'first_name' : fName,
          'mobile_no' : mobileNo,
          'last_name' : lName,
          'source' : 'app'
        });
        Response response = await dio.post("user/", data: formData);
        print(response.data);
      }
    }
```

and below is the page where I have stored all the formdata in Shared Preference

**register.dart**

```
    class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
    }
    
    class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage>{
      ApiService service = ApiService();
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      UserData _data = UserData();
      final setPadding = EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
      submit() async{
        if( this._formKey.currentState.validate()){
          _formKey.currentState.save();
    
          Map<String, dynamic> map = {
            'first_name' : _data.firstName,
            'last_name' : _data.lastName,
            'mobile_no' : _data.mobileNo,
            'email' : _data.email,
            'source' : 'app',
          };
    
          var user_obj = json.encode(map);
          SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          preferences.setString('user_data', user_obj);
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/otp', arguments: '${_data.mobileNo}'); 
          /* here to pass a mobile number to otp page, I had used Navigator 
             because from otp page I had to call verifyOtp(). Similarly how can I 
             pass the Shared Preference values to otp page because again I have 
             to call registerUser() which requires all those Shared Preference 
             values. Don't know I am correct or not! */
          print(_data.firstName);
          print(_data.lastName);
          print(_data.email);
          print(_data.mobileNo);
    
        }
        else{
          print('invalid credentials');
        }
      }
```

**router.dart**

```
    class RouteGenerator {
      static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashScreenPage());
          case '/register':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterPage());
          case '/login':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
          case '/otp':
            var mobNumber = settings.arguments as String;
            var fName = settings.arguments as String;
            var lName = settings.arguments as String;
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OtpPage(mobNumber, fName, lName));
          case'/home':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                          child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                    ));
        }
      }
    }
```

this is the page where I am calling that function

**otp_page.dart**

```
    class OtpPage extends StatelessWidget {
       String mobNumber, fName, lName;
       // String fName;
       // String lName;
      String formattedMobNo ;
    
      OtpPage(this.mobNumber, this.fName, this.lName){
        formattedMobNo = this.mobNumber.replaceRange(2, 8, 'XXXXXX');
      }
    
      ApiService service = ApiService();
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
      otpDecoration(double height, double width, Color color) {
        return PinTheme(
            shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            fieldHeight: height,
            fieldWidth: width,
            inactiveColor: color,
            activeColor: color,
            selectedColor: color);
      }
      TextEditingController pinController = TextEditingController();
      submit() {
       // _formKey.currentState.save();
        print(pinController.text);
        print(mobNumber);
        print(fName);
        print(lName);
    
        service.verifyOtp(mobNumber, pinController.text, _key);
        service.registerUser(fName, mobNumber, lName);
      }
```

can anybody please tell me how do I get those values and pass it to the function for calling an API?

actually the flow is on register page, after filling the fields and clicking on submit it will generate an otp and navigate to otp page. On otp page otp will be received and by clicking the proceed button it will verify the received otp and call the registerUser() which will call my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registerUser method is async so you can

```
 registerUser(String fName, String mobileNo, String lName) async{
    Dio dio = new Dio(options);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String info = await prefs.getString('user_data');
    Map map= json.decode(info);
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'first_name' : map['first_name'],
      'mobile_no' : map['mobile_no'],
      'last_name' : map['last_name'],
      'source' : 'app'
    });
    Response response = await dio.post("user/", data: formData);
    print(response.data);
  }
```

and decode info string in this method

if you want to pass data while using route generator you need to create model such as

```
class User {
String first_name;
String last_name;
String mobile_no;

User({this.first_name,this.last_name,this.mobile_no});
}
```

then you need to add this to your route generator

```
final args = settings.arguments;
case '/otp':
        if (args is User) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => OtpPage(
              user: args,
            ),
          );
        }
```

your otp page needs to be like that

```
class OtpPage extends StatelessWidget {
User user;
.
.
.
}
```

and your navigator must be like that

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String info = await prefs.getString('user_data');
Map map= json.decode(info);
User user = User(first_name:map['first_name'],mobile_no:map['mobile_no'],last_name: map['last_name']);

Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/otp', arguments: user);
```

Comment: Sorry! didn't get you @Hakkı Akut.

Comment: registerUser method is async method so you can use await so with using the code above you can get shared preferences and then you need to decode map and you can use it shared prefs.

Comment: Really thanks! @Hakkı Akut. But please consider my flow because I am unable to do such things.

Comment: i edited my answer again. I' m not sure if this is what you want but maybe will work for you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the shared_preferences dependency documentation:

You can get one or more value of your shared_preference by using multiples methods depending of your value type.

```dart
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

preferences.getBool("yourKey");
preferences.getString("yourKey");
preferences.getInt("yourKey");
preferences.getDouble("yourKey");

// ...
// You can also use the dynamic getter:

preferences.get("yourKey");
```

Since your set your value with a `.setString('user_data', user_obj);` method, you should use

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String storedString = prefs.getString('user_data');
```

Comment: Thanks! @BLKKKBVSIK. Did this but still I am facing issues.